# Chrome: autocomplete domain first?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, address-bar, omnibox

Firefox usually decides to be smart about this, and it actually works fairly well.
Lets say you have a google search cached. In Firefox, you can start typing in the address bar and it will only autocomplete up to "google.com" - in Chrome, it will instantly autocomplete the entire URL.

Is it possible to make Chrome mimic Firefox behavior in this respect? I find that wanting to go to the domain "root" is much more common than wanting to go directly to an exact URL - and even when it's not, Firefox makes sure those are kept a few arrow keystrokes away.

Comment: Why is this tagged with omnibox?

Comment: @Dave - why would it not be? The address bar in chrome is called "omnibox".

Comment: Oh.. ok.ithink it's also a virus and there is no tag description

Comment: @Dave I wouldn't know about that.All I know is that it's the Chrome address bar... oh. It's also the name of a streaming service. Who knew.

Comment: This question deserves WAY more love! Here we are now in 2023 and this is STILL incredibly annoying. Has anyone filed a ticket with chrome/chromium? Here's a reddit post with more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/fg5erz/url_autocomplete_should_suggest_the_base_address/

Comment: Agreed. This is just annoying behaviour on the part of Chrome.